# How Can I Read the Amount of Memory Being Used by Another Application Within My Program?

Tags: c#

To let me explain why I need to know, in my server launcher (for a game) someone requested that I added a 'Restart on Excessive Memory Usage' checkbox. So, after an hour or so of adventuring, I came here.

I just need to know how to read the memory usage of a running application and I can do the rest. I just have no idea how to do this withing a c# application.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755919/memory-usage-in-c-sharp Just change the "current process" to "another process".

Comment: When I do that, I get the following error. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Diagnostics.Process[]' to 'System.Diagnostics.Process'`

Comment: That means that whatever function call you did returned an array of processes instead of a single process like you tried to do. You must look at the array returned and select the correct element (if there are any elements in it at all)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain How exactly would I do that? Haha, I'm a bit new at this sorta thing.

Answer (score 8):

"Memory" is quite an inaccurate term on a demand-paged virtual memory operating system like Windows.  You need to pick one or more of these Process class properties:

- NonpagedSystemMemorySize64: a high value indicates that a device drivers have allocated lots of memory in the non-paged kernel memory pool.  Such memory is used for critical device driver operations that need to execute when devices generate an interrupt.  Not a very good measure unless you rely on a buggy driver.  Killing the process isn't typically going to help.
- PagedSystemMemorySize64: another driver resource, allocated from the paged kernel memory pool.  Typically used for I/O buffers.  Not typically a very good measure, getting a high value just indicates that your program is busy.  You however ought to correlate that with a steadily increasing HandleCount property value.  If that just keeps going up then you have a handle leak in the program that does merit killing it.
- VirtualMemorySize64: the total amount of virtual memory allocated for the process.  This covers both code and data used by the program, an OutOfMemoryException is raised when you run out of a hole big enough in the VM address space.  A pretty good measure for general leakage.
- WorkingSet64: the total amount of virtual memory actually mapped to RAM.  This number can heavily fluctuate as the operating system unmaps virtual memory pages to make room for other processes.  Not a good measure, you're likely to kill the process just because it got busy.  And a leaky program doesn't necessary have a large working set, many pages can be swapped out and not get swapped back in because a program doesn't typically reference leaked objects anymore.
- PrivateMemorySize64: the amount of virtual memory that's not shared with other processes, otherwise a better measure than VirtualMemorySize64 since it is representative for how many resources are allocated for just your process.  In a .NET app that will be data as well as code that wasn't ngen-ed.
- PagedMemorySize64: the amount of virtual memory that's backed by the paging file.  A good measure if you are leaking data, the normal problem in a leaky .NET app.

Some odds that when you check these numbers for your program to find out which one is best that you'll also have a good lead on the bug in your code.  A memory profiler can help a lot.  Fixing that bug is of course the far better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Process object to get everything about a running process. To get information about a running process you can call static method [Process.GetProcessByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That should give you details including memory use (this call returns array of all processes that match your name). To get the memory currently being used by the process use [Process.WorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Links referenced in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives you enough example to work with Process object.